# ImportError: No module named RC.Manager

Tags: import, module

I'm trying to install dataplicity but I always get this error. What do I have to install to solve this?

> ImportError: No module named RC.Manager

Answer (score 0):

Dataplicity developer here.  This issue has now been fixed.  You can either run the installer script again to update the dataplicity version (recommended) or if you installed manually you can run:

pip install -U dataplicity.